# How to implement Logistic regression with lasso or ridge?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, glmnet, lasso-regression

I have to implement a logistic regression and regularise with lasso or ridge and then calculate the RSS choosing the model that will shrinks up to 10 features or less.
I tried, using the package glmnet

```
x <- Train_set %>% dplyr::select(-Diag) %>%  as.matrix()

y <- Train_set$Diag  %>%  as.matrix()

Test_matrix <- model.matrix(Diag ~.,Test_set)[,-1]

Lasso <- cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha =1,family = "binomial")
```

Seeing that the desired model was that at 1 std I chose that. To get my prediction I used :

```
Lasso_1std <- glmnet(x,y alpha = 1, family = "binomial",lambda =Lasso$lambda.1se)

lasso_pred <- Lasso_1std %>% predict(newx  = Test_matrix)
#.....RSS_lasso




(Output_lasso <- data.frame(Test_set$Diag,lasso_pred))

#..........................RSS

(RSS_lasso <-(Output_lasso$Test_set.Diag - Output_lasso$s0)^2 %>% sum )
```

I do not know if I'm doing it the right way because I get 250 as RSS. A further question is if there is a way to do the same with caret :: train.

Comment: RSS is more frequently used for regression problems. Any specific reason why you want to use it for classification (logistic regression)?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/299653/caret-glmnet-vs-cv-glmnet answers all your questions.

Comment: It has been requested. I have to implement the code. Infact, This request is quite strange.